# Insert all data of a datagridview to database at once using mvc structure in C#.net

Tags: c#

i want to insert data into sql server from datagrid by using MVC structure

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer your question when you've put in zero effort so far to figure it out.  As such, I recommend you read through the MVC 4 tutorials to understand how it works.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4